# How to handle unreachable XMLHttpRequest endpoint

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have the following code which works as expected.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www......com', true);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.timeout = 2000;
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.response.success) {
   console.log(xhr.response.value);
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

Now, I'd like to handle when the third-party API is down and the endpoint is not reachable.

I have tried the following without success.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www......com', true);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.timeout = 2000;
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.response.success) {
   console.log(xhr.response.value);
  }
};
xhr.onerror = function() {
  console.log("There was an error");
};
xhr.send();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: "I have tried to catch any error" — There is no error handler in the code in your question. You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Quentin thank edited the comment to avoid misinformation

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `try/catch` to catch an asynchronous event.

(Unless you are using Promises with `async/await`, which you are not).

You need to use an [error event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onerror)

```
xhr.onerror = function() {
    console.log("There was an error");
};
```

---

The modern equivalent would be:

```
async function getJSON() {
   try {
       const response = await fetch(url);
       const data = await response.json();
       const status = response.status;
       return { status, data };
   } catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated to code (see edit) and now the console logs the error message but I still get the JS error as well.

Comment: @Sig — If your question is "How can I prevent the developer tools telling the user about network errors?": You can't. You can catch them so your code doesn't fail horribly, but they will still be reported.